# How to create a testing / temp in memory only DataTable using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

Is there any way to create a datatable with static value let say

```
Column : col1,col2.....coln
Rows : for n number of rows 

For first row values row11,row12......row1n
for second row values row21,row22.....row2n
.
.
.
for nth row values rown1,rown2......rownn
```

Any stylish way to do it using lambda/linq...may be in a single line in a expertise way ..

Comment: If your data is in XML format you can just pull it in to a DataTable.

Comment: What do you mean by "datatable"?

Comment: Use black background with golden font, if you want most stylish DataTable

Comment: @JohnSaunders I mean c# DataTables http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

Comment: @lazyberezovsky ..Sorry My bad ...here stylish not for visualization..i mean to say best way in programmatic way

Comment: That's not a "C# DataTable". It's a ".NET DataTable", specifically, ADO.NET.

Comment: More importanly, `DataTable` is an outdated technology. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @paqogomez ...no data source ...say for a static table

Comment: @JohnSaunders ..in my solution i need it badly ...any help

Comment: Again, "why"? Are you being required to use this specific class, or do you just need an in-memory data source?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41730/discussion-between-rahul-chowdhury-and-john-saunders)

Comment: "No datasource"?  Does that mean you are generating your data?  If there were code like "heres what I'm doing now" and data like "this is what i'm importing" this would be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders -- This seems like a standard task for a quick test case or POC -- are you grumpy today?

Comment: @Hogan -you are absolutely right .Its for quick test in a POC ..

Comment: @Hogan: For a quick test, it's easier to use `List<YourCustomRowType>`. No messing around with `table.Columns.Add` and such.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Not sure what you mean exactly -- maybe this could be an answer to enlighten us?

Comment: @Hogan: I'd love to enlighten you, but since the OP never said what he wanted to _use_ the DataTable for, that won't be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is an un-cool question ("outdated technology" - John Saunders) but I can't resist:

```
const int cols = 6;
const int rows = 20;

DataTable nt = new DataTable("new table");

nt.Columns
  .AddRange(
     Enumerable
      .Range(1,cols)
      .Select(x => new DataColumn("col"+x.ToString())).ToArray());

Enumerable
 .Range(1,rows).ToList()
 .ForEach(x => nt.Rows
                 .Add(
                  Enumerable
                  .Range(1,cols)
                  .Select(y => "row"+x.ToString()+"col"+y.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Sorry about the strange formatting but I did not want a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: ..Thanks for your reply ..I know its a "dumb" question..but you answered like a boss

Comment: @RahulChowdhury - Refresh -- I edited dumb to "un-cool".

Comment: Its ok man :) ...Its all about fun learning.It helped me  ..thanks again